# 'homey' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Tags: homey

I've created a Homey app but when I run `homey app run` I get `'homey' is not recognized as an internal or external command`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install Homey CLI first:

```
npm install --global homey
```

Also see: https://apps.developer.homey.app/the-basics/getting-started